# pydantic model - emit `null` for optional/required fields in the JSON string

Tags: python, pydantic

I've the following class defined using pydantic

```py
class Dummy(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[StrictStr] = None
    color_list: List[StrictStr] = Field(..., unique_items=True)


p = Dummy(color_list=["red","blue"])
```

Here is what the JSON representation looks like:

```
{
  "color_list": ["red", "blue"]
}
```

Is there a way I can mark `id` as nullable in pydantic so that JSON presentation will be as follows instead:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "color_list": ["red", "blue"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard [model.json()](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) returns all fields. But if you want to avoid null in the output you can use the `exclude_none` flag which is set to `False` default.

```py
...
>> p = Dummy(color_list=["red","blue"])
>> p.json()
{"id": null, "color_list": ["red", "blue"]}
>> p.json(exclude_none=True)
{"color_list": ["red", "blue"]}
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way to only mark `id` field to emit null (assuming there're 10 other fields in the model that's also null)? using `exclude_none=True` is almost what I want but I want to keep only 1 particular field emitting `null` in the JSON string.